# Edit box-header on Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: themes, post-thumbnails, dashboard

In my theme, I'm working with two featured images. One in square shape (preferably `500*500`) and one in widescreen (`1920*1080` for example).

However, it's not clear where which image has to go, when I make a new post, so I am looking into changing the title element of a box on the dashboard, so it's clear which image goes where.

See attached screenshot. I would like to add `500px*500px` after `Featured Image`, but I can't find out where I do this.
[image]

I tried by just adding it to my CSS file (with an `:after`-element), but it then hit me I can't target the Wordpress dashboard with the theme's CSS files.

Comment: It looks like you're using a plugin for multiple featured images, but you might try writing your own plugin to apply your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I clearly didn't know how to google, as [this page](http://biostall.com/how-to-change-the-wordpress-featured-image-meta-box-title/) already explains how to do exactly what I wanted. Adapting it a bit, for it to work with different post types, I came up with the following:

```
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'replace_featured_image_box');  
function replace_featured_image_box()  
{   
    $post_types = array('bwps', 'page', 'post');
    foreach( $post_types as $post_type ) {
      remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv', $post_type, 'side' );  
      add_meta_box('postimagediv', __('Featured Image <small style="opacity: .6">500*500</small>'), 'post_thumbnail_meta_box', $post_type, 'side', 'low');  
    }
}
```